# how to fix this error "'Exception' is a type, which is not valid in the given context" when use expression

Tags: c#

I have use this below code and pass the `type` as `string` and fullname as system.string

```
var instance = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(type), new List<MemberBinding>());
```

but, not get the instance and also exception occurs as mention below,

> Exception' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

when i pass the type as model in sample, it works.
But pass the type as string cases not works

Any one please give solution for this

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Type` from a `string` using the `Type.GetType` method:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.String")
```

Comment: To get the type above mention code okay, but i have to find and get the value for  instance from this code expression.memberinit(expression.New(type),new list());

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I have use below code                                                                                                  var instance = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(type), new List<MemberBinding>());                                                                                                                                      I have get exception when type as system.string

Comment: So what is `type` in your example...?